# VWO Segments: Track users using session Cookie

Tags: javascript, regex, session, cookies, vwo

We use Visual Website Optimizer, and we'd like to give a user the same look and feel permanently by putting him into a specific segment. Therefore we've considered using a regex that matches the last part of our session cookie.

How can I configure a Segment that matches the last 1 or 2 digits of a cookie like this?

```
javascript:document.cookie="session=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22ebaf6e7b3714129d17343e4aa"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To get last 1 or two digit characters.

```
string.match(/\d{1,2}(?=\D*$)/)
```